# Is it possible to create your own preview for Windows 10 Explorer?

Tags: windows, explorer

The Windows 10 preview pane in file explorer seems pretty useless to me and I usually hide it, but going through all my directories I think it would be really handy if I could write my own preview for things.

Specifically what I would want to do would be write something to preview directories.  If they were git repositories it could maybe show the last few commits.  If the directory had a `README.md` file it could display the formatted version.

Doing a little searching I didn't find any information on creating something like that, does Windows allow it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create and register shell extension.

Documentation, probably you need to implement this interface: [IPreviewHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775315(v=vs.85).aspx)

Some samples:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19744/Using-Preview-Handlers-in-Windows-Vista